# How to save a long string with in one cell

Tags: python, string, csv

I need to save a string which look like this:

`string = str(datetime.datetime.now())+' Buy market order on bitstamp on         %s/USD pair, by price %s\n withdraw from bitstamp to poloniex amount %s %s\n.Sell it on poloniex by price %s' % (coin, str(askprice_bits), str(start_coin_bal_polo), coin, str(bidpricepol))`

into single cell in csv file, by when I trying to save it  return me this string in 3 rows.

```
with open('document.csv','a') as fd:
    string = TheStringAbove
    fd.write(string)
```

the result is saved string in 3 rows(3 cells), I need to save it in one row.

Comment: Remove the 2 `\n` pieces in the string. Those write to a new line.

Comment: Don't use this "\n". It adds another row in your text

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose the string in double quotes (it contains separators and possible newlines).

For example you could have this csv record with 3 fields:

```
123,456,"str(datetime.datetime.now())+' Buy market order on bitstamp on         %s/USD pair, by price %s\n withdraw from bitstamp to poloniex amount %s %s\n.Sell it on poloniex by price %s' % (coin, str(askprice_bits), str(start_coin_bal_polo), coin, str(bidpricepol))"
```

This way that string can also contain newlines (i.e. multiline field).

If the string already contains double quotes, those have to be escaped with a second double quote:

```
123,456,"24"" monitor"
```